# Why is this link-only answer an audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers, first-answers

I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34813043). The audit expects the answer to be approved, not downvoted or flagged even though it is a link-only answer. Why is this an audit?

Comment: It is notable that this is a First Answers audit, in which reviewers are expected to handle issues beyond _just_ those that qualify for flagging.  ([cocomac's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425954/208273) expands on this a bit)

Answer (score 18):

Tl;dr: it *is* an answer, but it's a bad audit.

---

It's an answer, it's just a poor audit. Per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), the following counts as an answer, where `FileOutputStream` links to the documentation.

> You probably want a `FileOutputStream`

Note: the linked MSE question also states *if they're not useful*, they should be downvoted/removed. But... it does answer the OPs question, and got +13/-0 (as of now).

Arguably, that's what the answer you linked is: it's a link to the thing in the docs that (hopefully) does what the OP needs.

But... it's still a bad audit. There's *nothing wrong* with downvoting extremely short answers, *especially* when they attempt to get around a quality filter. I don't know what I'd *flag* as, given that the OP is essentially asking for a single thing from the docs, so it seems like it answers the question. But downvoting is fine, it's just a bad audit.

Comment: Honestly, once you remove the answer becomes, in it's entirety *"[`Dual`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Dual)"*, which should just be a comment.

Comment: @ThomA It could be a comment, correct, but like cocomac said, it is still an on-topic answer. One can argue to downvote it and 20k users may cast delete votes, but it is not against the rules and mods won't delete it when flagged (I assume).

Comment: @ThomA Not trying to be argumentative, but... how is that meaningfully different than "You probably want a `FileOutputStream`"...? As much as it isn't a very detailed answer, it seems to be valid under "Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?" Am I missing something...?

Comment: @ThomA Why should it? The question is asking for a type, the answer is giving it, it's an answer.

Comment: It's a link-only answer. It should be closed. Even if it's useful and cute.

Comment: @giusti It's not a link only answer, a link only answer only contains a link. This answer contains the name of the type, ergo, not link only.

Comment: Link only answers *are* against the rules of the site though, @Tom .

Comment: @ThomA it isn't link only though, even without the link `Dual` is still the answer to the question, it's not explained much, but that's not really asked or required by the question either. If the answer was "The type you're looking for is [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Dual)" then it would be a link only answer.

Comment: I can only disagree, it's a link only answer. There's *nothing* there but a link; everything else is noise. A picture of a cat is not helpful.

Comment: There is the requested types name... that's ***not*** nothing, that's the answer.

Comment: I never disputed it wasn't an answer, @cafce25 . Link only answers *are* an answer.

Comment: @ThomA Actually, link only answers _aren't_ answers, which is why they're supposed to be flagged as NAA. The whole thing that makes a link only answer link only is that it _only_ contains a link to the answer, and not the answer itself, making it not an answer. The answer in question actually contains the answer, and hence is not link only.

Comment: @ThomA do you have to click a link to find out the name of the requested type? If no then it's not link *only*.

Comment: I've stated what I've stated. I stand by it. If pixels emotes are now allowed to make link only answers accepted, so be it... ¯⁠\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯.. ಠ⁠︵⁠ಠ

Comment: @ThomA They are, correct, but since this post isn't link-only, it doesn't apply here.

Comment: I guess what is confusing here is that "link-only" isn't really explicit about what it actually means. It doesn't mean the link _and_ the link text could be ignored and the rest should be an answer, it only means the link, not the link text. So `<a href="url of documentation>loot at this</a>` is link-only, but `<a href="url of documentation">You need type Dual</a>` isn't. It tells you to use "Dual". It isn't a good answer because it doesn't explain how to use it, but it still give a pointer to the right direction without relying solely on the linked resource.

Comment: @Tom Where that gets even _less_ clear, is when a raw URL is in the answer, and the name of the thing is extremely clear inside the url, e.g. `<documentation URL>/types/Dual`. Some will call that link only, others won't.

Comment: It's "link only", not "link only *but with descriptive text*". If all there is in the "answer" is *a link*, it's ***link-only***. It's not like it takes much more effort to additionally copy/paste a brief documentation quote and provide a toy example.

Comment: @DrewReese Since both you and Thom A are so convinced, you should be able to easily prove it with site documentation.

Comment: The correct way to deal with this post would be to delete it. It doesn't matter if some meta lawyer can come up with an excuse to make it "an attempt to answer the question". It's a bad answer, we do not need to store bad answers or be afraid of deleting them. If the poster had been interested in explaining the term, they could have given the link _and_ quoted relevant parts from it on SO, so that the answer becomes stand-alone.

Comment: @Lundin Even if it's a bad answer, it can still be useful, especially since there are no other answers. If I find a Stack Overflow question through Google, I would much rather have a one-word answer with the correct class name (with or without a link) than no answers at all.

Comment: @ThomA Put it this way: If the answer were "Yep. That would be called Dual." (no link) would it still be link-only? You can identify a link-only answer when it gives you no information without clicking the link.  A pixel emote is _not_ information, so that would _not_ make an answer not link-only.  The name of a type, in response to a question asking for a type, _is_ information, so that _does_.